# if OSX Cocoa app uses WebKit, is it included in the executable or accessed like dll from the system?

Tags: macos, cocoa, webkit

on Windows a dotnet wrapper app around WebBrowser control would usually not incorporate the dll, so basically its executable would be small. How about a similar Cocoa custom browser using WebKit - will it be trivially small or will it incorporate the WebKit itself and hence be relatively hefty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default all system libraries on the Mac are dynamically linked. This includes WebKit. Otherwise, whenever you did a Mac OS X Software Update, none of the apps on the system would use the updated code.

WebKit updates are usually delivered whenever Apple updates Safari. If you install a new version of Safari, the new WebKit framework will be used by all apps that implement a `WebView`, unless those apps have linked to their own private version of WebKit.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably depend on how you build it?  It should be possible to use WebKit as a dynamic library.  For example if you take a look at Safari:

```
$ otool -L /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Safari.framework/Safari  | grep -i webkit
    /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 534.53.10)
    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit2.framework/Versions/A/WebKit2 (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 534.53.10)
```